# Nested function in Angular2 using TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am migrating from Angular 1 to 2, and I have nested functions in JavaScript:

```
function normalizeDoc(doc, id) {
    function normalize(doc){...
```

I removed the "function" but now I get errors from TypeScript.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class PouchSeed {

    constructor(

    ) {
    }

    normalizeDoc(doc, id) {
        normalize(doc) {
            doc = angular.copy(doc);
            Object.keys(doc).forEach(function (prop) {
                var type = typeof doc[prop];
                if (type === 'object') {
                    doc[prop] = normalize(doc[prop]);
                } else if (type === 'function') {
                    doc[prop] = doc[prop].toString();
                }
            });
            return doc;
        };

        var output = normalize(doc);
        output._id = id || doc._id;
        output._rev = doc._rev;
        return output;
    };
```

Errors:

```
Typescript Error
';' expected.
src/providers/pouch-seed.ts
normalizeDoc(doc, id) {
    normalize(doc) {
        doc = angular.copy(doc);

Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'normalize'.
src/providers/pouch-seed.ts
normalizeDoc(doc, id) {
    normalize(doc) {

Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'angular'.
src/providers/pouch-seed.ts
normalize(doc) {
    doc = angular.copy(doc);
```

Is it ok to nest methods like this? What's the reason for the ";" error?

Comment: `normalizeDoc` is a class method, so the `function` keyword is not used. `normalize` is just an ordinary function, to so the `function` keyword is required.

Comment: You can put `function` before `normalize`. So it will be the child function of `normalizeDoc`

Comment: Thanks that works fine! Can you help me on the last error too (cannot find name angular) ?

Comment: `doc = angular.copy(doc);` is `doc = { ...doc }` in TS 2.1+ or `Object.assign({}, doc)` in lower version

Comment: Great this works! (ionic2 is using TS 2.0). Do you also know the equivalent of `return angular.equals(local, remote);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `es2016` and `es2017` libraries to your compiler, in *tsconfig.json*:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      ..., "es2016", "es2017"
    ]
  }
```

You can use Object Spread, [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and TypeScript [deconstructing](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/destructuring.html):

```
export class PouchSeed {

  constructor() { }

  normalizeDoc(doc, id) {
    const normalize = o =>
      Object.entries(o)
        .map(([key, value]) => ({
          [key]: typeof value === 'object' ? normalize(value) ? typeof value === 'function' : value.toString() : value
        }))
        .reduce((acc, value) => ({ ...acc, ...value }), {});
    return { ...normalize(doc), _id: id || doc._id, _rev: doc._rev };
  };
}
```